# Очистка базы данных в приложении Django

Tags: python, django

Как очистить БД, полностью, если используется много сложных связей между моделями? При попытке дропнуть базу восстановить ее обратно уже не получится, даже простой запуск manage.py без аргументов начинает выдавать ошибки по поводу несуществующей таблицы auth.users.

Пробовал:

- Удаление миграций и попытки их перезапустить
- Полная очистка базы путем удаления всех таблиц
- manage.py flush

Все приводит к одному и тому же - ошибка по поводу несуществующей таблицы auth.users.

Comment: Вам в итоге полностью надо очистить или не очень полностью? Если не очень, то по какому принципу вы будете выбирать таблицы, подлежащие удалению?

Comment: Ну так создай эту таблицу, если удалил ее

Comment: @m9_psy полностью. То есть, полная очистка БД.

Comment: Не указана база данных, по ошибке похоже что mysql. Отключите проверку связей перед удалением, и проблем не будет. SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

Comment: Решение только для MyISAM и подобных, где файл на диске = таблица. Можно сразу удалить физически файл базы данных. Так же как и перенести с компьютера на компьютер можно не через дамп, а через файлы.

Comment: А принципиально именно очистить? По опыту такие проблемы возникают у тех,  у кого с миграцией не заладилось. Есть решение :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Да я уже давно разобрался, просто вспомнил про вопрос тут. На самом деле, бывает что нужно действительно именно полностью очистить базу. С тем, что миграции - очень удобная и полезная штука, даже спорить не буду, но все же иногда такая необходимость может возникнуть.

Comment: [режим некропостера включен] ошибка auth.users намекает, что вы скорее всего сами накосячили в коде и обращаетесь к базе там, где обращаться к ней нельзя, отсюда и все остальные проблемы

Answer (score 1):

К слову, помогал только полный дроп базы. Дело было в том, что структура БД была довольно сложной и запутанной, со множеством Foreign Key. Из-за этого при попытке аккуратно почистить базу появлялась проблема на этапе проверки целостности при удалении значений с Foreign Key.

Answer (score 1):

На будущее - если проблемы с миграциями на актуальной бд:

1. Делаете дамп
2. Пробуете применять миграции с ошибками как фейковые `python manage.py migrate <app> <migration_number>`
3. Пробуете применить остальные миграции `python manage.py migrate`
4. Если новая ошибка - п.2
5. Если кончились миграции и ничего важного нет в бд - дроп и пересоздание. Но лучше бойтись первые 4мя пунктами